# How to get Participant that called that transaction?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a transaction doSomething like such `doSomething(asset1, asset2)`.

Is it possible for me to retrieve the participant that called the `doSomething` transaction without passing in the participant reference as one of the arguments?

UPDATE:

```
doSomething(param1, param2) {
   //get caller participant reference here
   let caller = getParticipant();
}
```

For example, in the above transaction, I want to get a reference to the participant that called the transaction within that function (i.e. Transaction not done yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method getCurrentParticipant in the Runtime API that you can call from the Transaction Processing function.

In the more recent versions of Composer (certainly in v0.19.0) there is also getCurrentIdentity.

This [document](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest//api/runtime-api#getcurrentparticipant) in the API reference has the details.